# Cell width Jupyter notebook - Apache Toree - Scala

Tags: scala, jupyter-notebook, spark-notebook, apache-toree

How do I increase cell width of a Jupyter notebook with Apache Toree - Scala kernel?

The usual

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:100% !important; }</style>"))
```

indeed does not work.

Answer (score 2):

In `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js` (to avoid wrap - horizontal scroll):

```
$([IPython.events]).on('app_initialized.NotebookApp', function(){
  IPython.CodeCell.options_default['cm_config']['lineWrapping'] = true;
});
```

And added this in `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.css` (to use all width):

```
.container { width:100% !important; }
pre, code, kbd, samp {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

These two tricks help to make the Spark SQL DataFrame show() method a little more "palatable" by aligning columns to effectively kill word wrap and giving more width to the view. If these files do not exist, try creating them.

Comment: BTW- This is seeming a Jupyter question versus an Apache Toree question. Jupyter takes more responsibility for the notebook display.